# directed graph with python dataframe

Tags: python, directed-graph

```
I have a data frame like below: 
df=
Parent   Child
1087       4
1087       5
1087       25
1096       25
1096       26
1096       27
1096       4
1144       25
1144       26
1144       27

 I have tried this below code.. but not providing directed graph just giving graph which is not clear picture

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Build a dataframe with 4 connections

    df = pd.DataFrame([[k, i] for k, v in data.items() for i in v], 
                           columns=['parent', 'child']) 
    # Build your graph
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent', 'child')

    # Plot it
    nx.draw(G,pos=nx.spring_layout(G), with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

I would like like to convert this data frame into directed graph where source is parent and target is child.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `create_using` parameter in [from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html):

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent', 'child', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

The type of `G` after is `<class 'networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph'>` 
and the edges are:

```
(1144, 25)
(1144, 26)
(1144, 27)
(1096, 25)
(1096, 26)
(1096, 27)
(1096, 4)
(1087, 25)
(1087, 4)
(1087, 5)
```

Comment: Please Let me know how to find depth of this graph.